# Reference the class that a subview was added from

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, subview

I'm adding a subview to my primary iPad UIViewController, and within that subview I need to reference said view controller in order to play a video using that controller.

Can anyone help me out with the way that should be done, and possibly a code example?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Ed

EDIT (A LITTLE BIT MORE INFO):

This subview is a view from a uiviewcontroller class that is designed for the iPhone. It's a table that loads a video when a row is pressed. The movieplayer loads the video within the referenced viewcontroller (which is why I want to reference the iPad view controller from within the subview). The view is basically used within an iPad app in it's same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already have the main view living in a property of your application delegate (it is commonly assigned via the application's .xib file, look in the app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching: method, where it adds the main view as a subview to the window, something like:

```
[window addSubview:primaryController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

).

So anywhere in your app where you need to access the main view, you can do:

```
[(MyAppDelegateType*)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).primaryController somePrimaryControllerMethod];
```

Edit: while this will work, I agree with Rob Napier that this isn't the best way to do it, architecture-wise.

Comment: Don't try to rendezvous with other view controllers using the app delegate. This makes the code very hard to reuse. If you ever rearrange your UI (adding a tab controller), the whole technique will break.

Comment: Well, that depends. The main view controller is usually not a plain UIViewController, but an app-specific subclass of that. So as long as you only call the methods you've written yourself (like playMyCoolVideo), you can easily substitute the main controller with another one (e.g. an iPad version).

Comment: The issue is the hook through the app delegate. The app delegate isn't a global dumping ground for globals. If you need to rendezvous with a specific, related view controller, make the view controller a singleton, not app delegate property. Putting it in the app delegate makes it very hard to change the UI architecture later, and hard to move these view controllers into another project.

Comment: This isn't exactly a dumping ground since the main view controller is a rather unique thing (and the corresponding app delegate property is actually auto-generated with the new app stub, I believe). But I see your point and I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. In terms of the way I have things set up right now, this is the best option for me.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an architecture problem. It's not up to your view to tell something to play a sound. That's a controller's job. It's up to your view to tell "someone" that it was touched, or slid, or whatever the user has done. "Someone" (who is watching) will then perform the correct response to that.

To do this, your view should generally take a target, and possibly and action. Look at how `UIControl` (for example, `UIButton`) informs other objects that it has been activated. The observer (controller) then reacts accordingly.

**EDIT**

The view should not load a video. A view controller should load the video and install it into the correct view. The only job the view has is to tell its view controller that it has been pressed. `UITableView` handles this automatically with the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. If you're not using a `UITableView`, you should still follow this pattern. The view accepts has a delegate and tells the delegate (controller) that something was selected. Then the controller updates the views with the new data.

Comment: Hi Rob, I've added to my question. Does that make any more/less sense?

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the edit. I know that, the table is within a UIViewController, and that has all the methods in there. But obviously, when I'm referencing the view to show on the iPad, there isn't the views viewcontroller to show the video (only sound plays).

Comment: I don't understand what this means. What do you mean "obviously...there isn't the views viewcontroller to show the video?" That doesn't sound obvious at all. Are you mixing "view" and "view controller?" I don't understand what classes you mean here. I don't know what "only sound plays" means. Is that what you want, or what is happening? Are you using an MPMoviePlayer?

Comment: Hi Rob, apologies! Ok.

I have the UIViewController with an associated nib and view inside. This is used on the iPhone version of the app. Within my iPad view controller, I add the view from the iPhone app as a subview.

Within the iPhone UIViewController the tableview didSelectRow method loads the correct video using MPMoviePlayer, passing in the viewcontroller as a parameter to define where to play the video within. I can hear the sound in the background, but no video.

Comment: Your problem likely is that something along the way is `nil`. Check that the `viewController` parameter, the `view`, any IBOutlets, etc. are not `nil`. In particular, remember that none of your IBOutlets are set until `viewDidLoad` is called. You may want to start over with a new question that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `[yourSubview superview]` to get the superview.

Comment: The OP is looking for the view controller, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a property to the view like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *parentViewController;
```

And on initialization of the view (from within the UIViewController), set the property:

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
customView.parentViewController = self;
```

And from then on you should be able to call the parentViewController from within the view.

**Edit:** Rob Napier has a good point, it's probably a better idea to set a target and selector from within the view instead of a view controller. This way you should be able to hook up methods directly with the view. The properties would look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic assign) id target;
@property (nonatmic, assign) SEL selector;
```

And perhaps add a designated initializer to your view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:aFrame];
   if (self)
   {
      self.target = aTarget;
      self.selector = aSelector;
   }
   return self;
}
```